# Angular is it possible to sort array alphabetically in ngFor?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I need to sort my ngFor alphabatically here is my code

```
<div *ngFor="let main of data.mainCategories; let i = index" class="category-container">
  <ion-grid class="categories-card5" no-padding>
  <ion-row><ion-col class="ion-text-center">
  <ion-item lines="none" button="true" (click)="showSubCategory(i)" detail="false">
    <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
      <img *ngIf="main.image?.src" src="{{main.image.src}}">
    </ion-thumbnail>
    <ion-label>
      <h2 [innerHTML]="main.name"></h2>
      <h2 [innerHTML]="main.slug"></h2>
      <p [innerHTML]="main.description"></p>
    </ion-label>
    <ion-icon *ngIf="main.show" name="chevron-up-outline" mode="ios" color="medium"></ion-icon>
    <ion-icon *ngIf="!main.show" name="chevron-down-outline" mode="ios" color="medium"></ion-icon>
  </ion-item>
</ion-col>
</ion-row>
</ion-grid>
</div>
```

In this i have `main.slug` i need to sort it by this example in `main.slug` which start alphabet is a it will show first like this

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to sort them within what you're looping from.

Sample:

```js
const mainCategories = [
  { name: 'Category B', slug: 'B' },
  { name: 'Category A', slug: 'A' },
  { name: 'Category E', slug: 'E' },
  { name: 'Category C', slug: 'C' }
]


mainCategories.sort((a, b) => (a.slug > b.slug) ? 1 : -1)

console.log(mainCategories);
```

Answer (score 1):

one solution is to order the array that you currently have into a new array and use `*ngFor` on that.

```js
class YourComponent {

  mainCategories: object[]  
  sortedCategories: object[];

  constructor() {
    this.sortedCategories = this.mainCategories.sort(this.sortBySlug);
  }

  sortBySlug(a: object, b: object): number {
    // this is the typical structure of a custom sort function in plain JavaScript

    if (a.slug < b.slug) { return -1; }
    if (a.slug === b.slug) { return 0; }
    if (a.slug > b.slug) { return 1; }
  }
}
```

You can also create a custom pipe if you want as well. I made a custom stackblitz repo that you can follow [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngfor-sort-pipe). The pipe I created simply applies a specified sort function to the array.

Hope this helps.